# Функция соединения Клиентского сокета WSAConnect с удаленным сервером

Tags: winsock

Позвольте вопрос:

После создания клиентского сокета с помощью функции WSASocket(), далее необходимо установить соединение с удаленным сокетом сервера(по TCP) с помощью функции WSAConnect() - вторым параметром, которой является указатель на структуру sockaddr - первым параметром, которой является значение протокола, который я должен указать, для соединения с удаленным сервером - это или AF_INET(ipv4) или AF_INET6(ipv6)

Но, я не могу понять, как я могу это указать, если я не знаю на каком протоколе работает оборудование на кортом установлен сервер или поддерживает само ПО сервера какой то их этих двух версий протокола.

Answer (score 0):

Делайте по ipv4. Он с нами еще надолго. Когда все заработает - можно попрбовать по ipv6, но в реальности мало кто поддерживает его - не везде маршрутизируется еще

По вопросам в комментариях я решил немного расширить ответ.

когда происходит разрешение буквенного именив ip адрес- DNS может вернуть как адреса в формате IPv4, так и адреса в формате Ipv6, например:

```
    nslookup mail.ru
    Server:  UnKnown
    Address:  192.168.0.2

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name:    mail.ru
    Addresses:  2a00:1148:db00:0:b0b0::1
              94.100.180.200
              217.69.139.202
              217.69.139.200
              94.100.180.201
```

Здесь первый адрес - ipv6, остальные - ipv4

И с любым из этих адресов можно вызывать функцию.

Comment: S.H., так то оно понятно :)                                                                                                                                                         Но это же не совсем правильно ? То есть в функцию WsaConnect - включили опцию "предугадывания" получается ? Ну то есть условно, написал я скрипт, который делает просто Connect c сервером по ipv4, сервером меняет протокол на ipv6 - все коннекта нет? Но в браузере явно такой проблемы не будет, иначе бы все рушилось при переходе серверов на ipv6. ?

Comment: Вы не поверите, но когда пишешь сетевые программы - там даже при вводе адреса угадывать приходится. Потому что нет способа по введенному в строку браузера адресу понять, что это - IP или адрес домена? И правильным способом считается такой: делаем соедиениние, считая что это -IP, если не получилось - переходим к резрешению буквенных имен. И, кстати, IP в строку можно вписать термя способами, как минимум.

Comment: S.H., так разве дело в том, сколькими способами можно вписать IP в строку ? Если я клиент и пишу в качестве адрес не прямой IP а его буквенное имя, DNS возвратит - его реальный IP, но, как до вызова функции Connect - узнать, как протокол поддерживает сам сервер, который использует этот IP. Браузеры явно работают только с ipv4 и ipv6, неужели в барузере жёстко забито ipv4 ?? Как тогда они открывают сайты работающие на Ipv6 ?

Comment: Никак. Адрес, котрый возвратит DNS никак не связан с набором протоколов, котрые поддерживает IP. Этот IP даже  не обязан существовать. А WsaConnect  не предугадывает - она будет пытаться открыть соединение с теми параметрами протокла, с котрыми её вызовут

Comment: Хочу немного исправить свойответ. Когда DNS при  разрешении имен вернет ipv6 -браузей пойдет по ipv6. Если DNS вернет IPv4 - браузер пойдет по IPv4. Если и тои другое вернет - не знаю, но думаю, что предрочтение будет отдано ipv6
Еще - браузеры делают кучу работы, которая включает в себя, например, попытку запросить favicon при открытии сайта